# How to use boolean checkbox with Node, MySQL Handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to insert a boolean value of 1 or 0 if the checkbox is checked into the MySQL database, or a value of 0 if it's unchecked. However the page seems to not render and isn't properly adding the value to the database. Here is my router.post for my exercise.js file

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
        var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
        var sql = "INSERT INTO workouts (name, reps, weight, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        var inserts = [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date];
        sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
                if(error){
                        res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                        res.end();
                } else{
                        if(req.body.checked === true){
                                var sqlcheck = "INSERT INTO workouts (lbs) VALUES(1)";
                                var checkinserts = [req.body.lobs];
                                sqlcheck = mysql.pool.query(sqlcheck, checkinserts, function(error, results, fields) {
                                        if(error){
                                                res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                                                res.end();
                                        } else{
                        res.redirect('/exercise');
                }
            });
        };
    }
});
});
```

Here is my Handlebars file that handles the checkbox.

```
<h1>MySQL Results:</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Exercise Name</th>
        <th>Reps</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Lbs</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each exercise}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{reps}}</td>
            <td>{{weight}}</td>
            <td>{{date}}</td>
            <td>{{lbs}}</td>
            <td><button onclick="deleteExercise({{id}})">Delete</button></td>
            <td><a href="/{{id}}">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    <form id="addexercise" action="/exercise" method="post">
    Exercise Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Reps: <input type="number" name="reps"><br>
    Weight: <input type="number" name="weight"><br>
    Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
    Lbs: <input type="checkbox" name="checked" {{bindAttr checked="isChecked"}})><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</table>
```

Do I have to put a create a function when the button is checked?

Comment: add appropriate "value" attribute to checkbox input

Comment: I did add a value but it's still showing as null like so - any idea why?

Comment: Lbs: <input type="checkbox" name="checked" {{bindAttr checked="isChecked" value =1}})><br>

Comment: can you paste the checkbox input html from view page source?